# PHP opendir issue

Tags: php, opendir

Why do I get this error even though the directory exists? it works fine if I target the parent directory, I tried using %20 instead of space too, and tried removing the last / but nothing works!

**Warning:** opendir(/home/xxxx/user_files/users/xxxx/test directory/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in **/home/xxxx/public_html/beta/stream._pages/file._list._i.php** on line 54

(Note: **xxxx** is just me censoring user names)

Comment: It seems that there is an issue with spaces in the directory name. How can I make it **ALLOW** the use of spaces?

Comment: I think you are missing public_html in your url.

Comment: /home/xxxx/user_files/users/xxxx/test directory/ doesn't seem a right path to me.

Comment: no, I am not miss public_html, the user_files directory is **outside** of public_html. I am able to access */home/xxxx/user_files/users/xxxx/nospace/* fine or */home/xxxx/user_files/users/xxxx/*, but not */home/xxxx/user_files/users/xxxx/test directory/*

Comment: does the directory physically exist?

Answer (score 0):

Make a file called test.php and put it in your test directory. In that file, put this code:

```
<? echo dirname(__FILE__);?>
```

Then, visit test directory/test.php in your web browser, copy and paste the path as given in test.php and try using that exact path in opendir.

Another issue might be that the permissions of your directory aren't right, try chmodding to 777

Comment: yea that came to my mind but the folder isn't under public_html. maybe he could do this via ssh + php CLI.

Comment: Yeah... I can't access it via the browser to do this. What would the command be to do it via SSH?

Comment: I tried to do `cd 'test directory'` via ssh, but it doesn't work, though I can do `cd nospace` fine here too. *smh*

Comment: allas, replacing spaces with `\ ` doesn't work for opendir. :'(

Comment: did you try running the file test.php? whats the output

Comment: how do I run the test.php in terminal after I cd?

Comment: Also, I am using a variable when calling the `opendir()` function, so I can't use quotes to escape the path what I am doing looks like this: `opendir($direct)`.

Comment: SOOOOOO.... it turns out it was a typo. The directory was called 'test driectory' **facepalm**

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to find the folder outside of the public_html folder.

This code is provided by php.net for the [`opendir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) function:

```
if ( $handle = opendir('../../../../') )
{
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while ( false !== ( $entry = readdir( $handle ) ) )
    {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    /* This is the WRONG way to loop over the directory. */
    while ($entry = readdir($handle))
    {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir( $handle );
}
```

**Solution**

The `$handle` I started checking out how far I could go back with `'../'` adding as much ../ as possible until you find yourself in the folder you need. From there you take I guess.

For me `'../../../../'` was enough to get there, it's different on every server.